# Better splitting of mutliallelic sites then bcftools norm --m-any

Tags: vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools

I am trying to split the multiallelic sites of my VCF. I used `bcftools norm --m-any`. However, the result is not really reasonable to me. Here's an example.

Let's say, I have this multiallelic site:

```
REF     ALT     GT1     GT2     GT3
A       C,G     1/2     0/2     0/1
```

After splitting I get these two:

```
REF     ALT     GT1     GT2     GT3
A       C       1/0     0/0     0/1
A       G       0/1     0/1     0/0
```

So, the results for the "unused" `ALT` allele for a specific row is just set to `REF`. Is there a way to change this behavior, since I don't think it's reasonable to do it this way, at least for my analysis. I would like my result to be more like this:

```
REF     ALT     GT1     GT2     GT3          GT1     GT2     GT3
A       C       1/.     0/.     0/1    or    ./.     ./.     0/1
A       G       ./1     0/1     0/.          ./.     0/1     ./.
```

Or similar. At least I don't want to have `REF` where there was an `ALT` before.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try `bcftools norm -a .` ?

You can also check the `--atom-overlaps` option: 'Alleles missing because of an overlapping variant can be set either to missing (.) or to the star alele (*), as recommended by the VCF specification.'

Comment: Yes, this option was implemented quite recently due to our request on GitHub. Haven't tried it yet, since it wasn't in the latest release available via conda. I will try that, but I solved this problem differently by using `vt decompose -s`.

Comment: is there a mention of bcftool norm in any publication?

Comment: @DeathMetal: If you want to cite bcftools: [link](https://doi.org/10.1093/gigascience/giab008) , article cited ~3,000 times.